# вою на луну - значение

Tags: перевод, значения

Would someone be willing to explain the meaning of the song to me? I can understand each word, but the sentences dont make any sense to me.
There seems to be so much idiom, there must be much more meaning in the song than I get just from translating it.

I hope this is not inappropriate to ask, but the song really interests me. Its a great song.

Comment: :D I'm afraid that song should be taken word for word, there are no idioms in it. The girl is talking with the Moon ("howling at the Moon") about the guy with whom she's been apart for 2 weeks ("for a long time")... Questions asking for translations are off-topic unless prior research effort is clearly indicated; we're here to help you learn, not provide a bulk translation service.

Comment: That helps actually to add context actually, I can take another look with that in mind.

Comment: I understand about the bulk translation - its a lot to ask

Comment: @YellowSky Is she avoiding him, yet sad about it?

Comment: No, she says "это была не я" - "[the cause] was not [in] me", it was the destiny, "судьба". She wants to drive away the Moon in order to stop thinking about him. "Ты" in the song refers to the Moon.

Comment: What does she mean by "if you wait a while, and dont lose what I find?"

Comment: Why does she say "There is no trace of sadness?"

Comment: Is she urging him on (ты беги беги догоняй меня)? (Is she using imperative with the subject ты?)

Comment: @YellowSky shouldve addressed earlier for the above comments

Comment: "If you wait a while, and don't lose what I find" doesn't make any sense. "There is no trace of sadness" is actually "There is no use to be sad". "Tы беги беги догоняй меня" is "Run, run after me" - it's addressed to the Moon (I already wrote: "Ты" in the song refers to the Moon). Using imperative with the subject "ты" in Russian is the stylistically neutral and means the same as without "ты".

Comment: @YellowSky is that a fair translation? Ты если подождешь немного/
и не потеряй то , что нахожу

Comment: Yes, you translated it correctly, but I cannot see any meaning behind those words. In my first comment I said this song is of rather low poetic quality, I don't know why you liked it so much.

Answer (score 4):

Infact, it is an idiom. The expression is **"выть на луну́"** which means **"to be extremely sad, depressed"**, **"to despair deeply"** or **"to miss someone or something too much"**. Its literal translation is "to howl at the moon", that is what wolves and dogs do at night.

Comment: That actually helps alot too